# Not receiving callback in onActivityResult() after sending invite request to Google plus

Tags: android, google-plus

not receiving callback in onActivityResult() after sending invite request to Google plus

```
public void sendGooglePlusInvite(){
Intent intent = new AppInviteInvitation.IntentBuilder(getActivity().getString(R.string.app_name))
            .setMessage(getActivity().getString(R.string.invite_message_less))
            .setCustomImage(Uri.parse(getActivity().getString(R.string.app_image_url)))
            .build();
    getActivity().startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_INVITE);
}
```

on call back in

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(...);
    if (resultCode == getActivity().RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_INVITE) {
            // Get the invitation IDs of all sent messages
            String[] ids = AppInviteInvitation.getInvitationIds(resultCode, data);
            for (String id : ids) {
                Log.d("TAG", "onActivityResult: sent invitation " + id);
            }
        }
    } else {
        // Sending failed or it was canceled, show failure message to the user
        // ...
    }
}
```

Please help me

Comment: `onActivityResult` is in `Fragment` or `Activity`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can't receive callback by this way:

To get the result in your fragment make sure you call `startActivityForResult(intent,REQUEST_INVITE);` instead of `getActivity().startActivityForResult(intent,REQUEST_INVITE);` inside your fragment.

And secondly make sure you implement this method in your activity:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
   super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

this will call your fragment's `onActivityResult()`